# Invalid conversion from char to const* char, What is wrong with the code?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

i'm trying to write a function which takes one int parameter and returns sum of it's digits.For example, digital_root(123) will return 1+2+3 which is 6.And inside the for loop i can't convert individual character to integer..

it should be included that i used both atoi() and stoi() functions.What is wrong with the code?

```
int digital_root(int x)
{
    int t = 0;
    string str = to_string(x);
    for(char& c : str){
        t += atoi(c);
    }
    return t;
}
```

i expect the characters to convert to integer successfully.how can i do so?

Comment: You don't need to introduce or use any strings to add up the digits.  Think about division by 10 and modulus.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get an error? Exception? Your question is not so explicit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in

Comment: If you insist to use string-way to do calculation, may be the `str.substr(i, 1)` can be accepted by atoi()/stoi().

Comment: Is there other convenient function that i could have used? Why using strings is a bad idea?

Comment: @user32350 The convenient function is a simple `while` loop, dividing by 10 and summing the remainder.  Very fast..  Using strings requires a conversion from the int to a string, which is a tiime waster.

Comment: [See how simple it is?](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b8510df565f663b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`std::atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi), its argument is of type `const char*`, but you are passing a single `char`. There is no possible conversion from `char` to `const char*`, this is what the compiler complains about.

What you want instead is converting the `char` to an int by doing some ASCII math:

```
t += static_cast<int>(c)  - '0';
```

But note that while this works, there is a better solution for this task. It doesn't require the conversion to a string, but instead relies on integer division solely, repeatedly using `% 10`.

Comment: Is there a way to get char type through for loop ?

Comment: I dont't get that question, the loop variable is already of type `char&`?!

Comment: As you said i need const* char type to use atoi and stoi function . So how should i change my for loop so that i can work with const* char rather than char? (I mean c variable as a const* char)

Comment: Well you could convert each single `char` into a null-terminated string, and then pass `std::string::c_str()` to `atoi`. But note that while this might work, it makes absolutely no sense to do such a thing. And iterating over `const char*` isn't possible because a `std::string` is a sequence of `char`, not of `const char*`.